# My macbook pro 2018 is making this strange buzzing (white/grey noise) sound on repeat?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, headphones

Just recently I have noticed this strange noise coming from my MacBook. It sounds like static, or grey noise, but it's not continues, it starts and stops in a constant repeating manner, almost like a slowed beat. Like:

```
_ _  _ _  _ _  _ _
```

I removed my headphones and plugged it back in, keeps going...

What is this?

Comment: its unclear, is the noise coming from the speakers and not the headphone?

Comment: @SteveChambers its not coming from the headphones that's fr sure. Could it be coming from the fan? Idk.

Comment: Are you on AC or battery? What other cables do you have attached to the machine?

Comment: it could be coming from lots of places, you need to determine if it is coming from speakers and/or headphones. raise/lower volume does the noise go up/down with it? It could be coming from anything that generates sound meaning anything that moves (fans, rotational drives, etc) or your speaker/headphones system.

Comment: @SteveChambers  I unplugged everything and the noise continues, I raise and lower the volume, it does not seem to affect it. I will test the fan right now by running a big programme

Comment: @SteveChambers update: So Now that my fan is running at close to max, I have observed an increase in the volume of the noise (although mixed with the fan noise also), and notably I think, is that it's no longer got continuous repeating pattern I noted in my question body. Now is simply a continuous grey noise without any pauses or beat.

Comment: The key comment here is "although mixed with the fan noise..." That would tend to indicate *it ain't the fan.* The problem here is diagnosing a noise here in AD when this is best diagnosed, in person, by an experienced computer tech.

Comment: @Awsome_user Can you confirm that this is happening **both** when you are running from **AC power** *and* when you're only on **battery power**?

Comment: @pion yes I can and do confirm

Comment: Does it make this noise if you boot into the Boot Picker (hold Option during boot) and leave it there for 10 minutes?